# Best Way to Gracefully Shutdown a Java Command Line Program

Tags: java, command-line, shutdown

I'm interested in different approaches to gracefully shutting down a Java command line program.  Sending a kill signal is not an option.

I can think of a few different approaches.

1. Open a port and wait for a connection.  When one is made, gracefully shutdown.
2. Watch for a file to be created, then shutdown.
3. Read some input from the terminal, such as "execute shutdown".

The third one is not ideal, since there is often program output pumped to the screen.  The first one takes too much effort (I'm lazy).  Do most programmers use the second option?  If not, what else is possible/elegant/simple?

Comment: You mean for a process to kill your java command line program?

Comment: Why is sending the kill signal not an option? As mentioned in answers below, you can catch and handle the kill signal gracefully with shutdown hooks.

Answer (score 18):

you can try something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { /*
       my shutdown code here
    */ }
 });
```

**edit:**

the shutdown hook will not perform the shutting down of the app.  instead, it gives the developer a way to perform any clean-up that he/she wishes at shutdown.

from the JavaDoc for [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) (a good read if you are planning to use this method):

> A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread. When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently. When all the hooks have finished it will then run all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled. Finally, the virtual machine will halt. ...

Comment: How does that shutdown his program?

Comment: Shouldn't the run method have an @Override annotation?

Comment: Will this work when I close the command prompt by clicking on "x" button (Windows)?

Comment: No idea why this answer has the most upvotes -  it is completely irrelevant (*does not* perform the shutdown, which is what the OP is asking for)

Comment: @JanakaBandara it's not what OP asked for but it's what people are looking for

Answer (score 8):

you could try to use `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` that should satisfy your requisite. In this way you can register an hook to do cleanups, in order to perfom a gracefull shutdown.

**EDIT**

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)
public void addShutdownHook(Thread hook)
Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.
The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:

- The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
- **The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C**, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

Comment: But mike, its the way to degrade gracefully, if a ctrl+c is pressed, any cmd program will be terminated with a kill signal.

Comment: None of the other options you mentioned would either though, so the behavior on ctrl+c probably isn't relevant to deciding on one of these methods.

Comment: the javadoc explicitly say that it is invoked on ctrl-c

Comment: I just tested and the shutdown hook is invoked on ctrl-c (at least on Mac OS X 10.5 running java 1.5.0_16)

Comment: Beware -Xrs java command line option: it masks SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, and SIGQUIT.

Comment: Irrelevant (*does not* perform the shutdown, which is what the OP is asking for)

Comment: Note, that under bash, when java program is executed with pipe to other program (i.e. tee), ctrl+c will not trigger shutdown hook...

Answer (score 6):

The benefit of the second option - checking for a file - over the first - listening on a port - is that you have some possibility of security.

You can set the permissions on the directory where the file is created so that only appropriate users can close the program.  If you listen on a port any user can connect to it.

Comment: You could limit the incoming calls based on the client IP address. For example allow connections only from localhost. You only exit when it is the proper IP address, otherwise close the connection and continue listening for a new one.

Comment: @kd304 - Limiting IP addresses still allows any user on local system to shut down the process.  By setting permissions on the directory you can only allow a specific user control of the process.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to go with the socket version, it is very simple to implement. Here's the code:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
System.out.println("Socket listening!");
server.accept();
System.out.println("Connection received!");
```

You could easily embed this code in a separate thread that you start with your program, and then have it modify global state to initiate shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

The first two option is simple to implement. You could also use some JMX stuff (I don't know much about that). Tomcat uses the first approach and I applied 1 and 2 in two of my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Consider having a JMX component.  Then you can attach with JConsole either locally or over the network, and communicate with your component.  Then the component can shut down the program properly.

With Java 6 u 10 or later, you can do the same with JVisualVM.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use the shutdown hook. It will allow your program do be controlled using standard OS tools. It also does not need any additional access to external resources (disk, ports, whatever).

Comment: This *does not* perform the shutdown, which is what the OP is asking for