# Java, managed application shutdown as response to CTRL^D

Tags: java, event-handling, shutdown, multiplatform

I have developed a Java online distributed application which usually active all the time (**not GUI**).

I am interested to perform some steps before the shutdown in case the administrator is interested in such shutdown.

I know that CTRL^C stops the JVM, i wonder if i can hook CTRL^C and execute some additional operations before JVM shutdown, or add some hook to a CTRL^D event in order to do the same thing.

I almost sure there is a post somewhere describes similar questions , and i would appreciate links to such posts.

i am not interested in any third party external jars or any JNI solution.

I will appreciated a code example snippet if there is no post discussing the same question.

Additional constraint: **This solution should work both for UNIX and Windows.**

**Edit**

One solution that was proposed here is the use of `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {})`

As far as i understand a new thread is created which will listen and wait to the shutdown event to happen.

1. I wonder if somehow i can signal the main thread that a shutdown occurred ( I have a distributed system as i mentioned , and i need to inform each single thread of such event)?
2. May i add multiple thread to listen for this event?

Comment: On Unix systems, Ctrl+D ends the standard input. Ctrl+whatever is handled by the terminal. So you can't hook Ctrl+whatever in the Java program.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028687/best-way-to-gracefully-shutdown-a-java-command-line-program

Comment: @ignis: CTRL^* IS NOT MUST, any other combination is welcome

Comment: @beny23: +1,Thanks , i missed this post, hope it will help, i'll go over it now

Comment: @beny23: Please see my EDIT, i am sorry that i have updated the question and i probably had to open a new one, i will really appreciate an answer to the extended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To react to CTRL+C you have to add a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'll be back!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i have read this solution in the post in the comment supplied by beny23

Comment: Please see my EDIT, i am sorry that i have updated the question and i probably had to open a new one, i will really appreciate if you can extend your answer.