# Gracefully shutting down a program using the presence of a file - Good or bad?

Tags: java

Assume I have a daemon-style Java program (one that repeatedly executes a code block *forever* until terminated). I have code in it to periodically check for the presence of a file, and if present, delete the file and gracefully shut the program down.

To shut down the program, rather than `kill`ing its process, I would simply `touch` the file and wait for the program to shut down (and for the file to disappear).

- Is this a good practice or bad practice? What are the reasons?
- What other ways can the graceful shut down of a Java program be implemented?

*Note: I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028687), however none of the answers satisfy the questions above.*

Comment: Have you considered using signals? "kill" is a signal to a process, if you write signal handlers, you can communicate with the process using them. See this link for more info: http://goo.gl/PI0wfF . IMO, the question you linked in your question **does** answer your question about how to shut down a program gracefully.

Comment: `kill`ing a process is nothing bad, it is more something like: "Would you be so kind to shut yourself down?". (-9 is bad!)

Comment: I don't see how your question is different from the linked question..

Comment: @Ishtar there are numerous answers in the linked question but none talk about the merits and demerits of each method to achieve this.

Comment: There is only one way to gracefully exit, that is to clean up just before terminating: addShutdownhook. If you have to exit when a file exists, sure just call System.exit.

Answer (score 1):

What if the process crashes? Now the file exists and the program will never start up again?
I've seen this mechanism used before, and that's always a weak point.

Comment: The file can be deleted when the program is started up. Or if the program is designed to "consume" the file, it will be deleted on a first start up that fails, so a second start up will go fine.

Comment: @ADTC nice in theory, but often such things are designed as a crude means of locking the system against having multiple instances running. Far better to just listen for a kill signal.