# thread pool server shut down gracefully

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown, httpserver

I have a simple http server implemented with  thread pool. I want to shut down the server gracefully.  I referred the post [Best Way to Gracefully Shutdown a Java Command Line Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028687/best-way-to-gracefully-shutdown-a-java-command-line-program)
Here is the basic code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolServer threadserver = new ThreadPoolServer(9000);
    new Thread(threadserver).start();
    threadserver.attachShutDownHook();
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20 * 10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void stopthread(){
    this.shutdown = true;
    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}

public synchronized void attachShutDownHook() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            stopthread();
        }
    });
}
```

But it seems  it does not stop the right way, any ideas? Thx.

Comment: It does not stop the right way means? Can you explain the problems you faced?

Answer (score 0):

This is too small piece of code.

But at the first sight I don't see any check for shutdown value in the main while loop. Secondly the variable should be set after and probably join on the listening thread would be worthy. In the run method I assume you properly handle the exception raised by asynchronous close.